# How to show $x\sum_{k>x} C/k^2 \ln k$ converges to $0$

Tags: probability-theory

It's a question from Durrett's Probability Theory textbook.

> Suppose $X_1,X_2, \dots$ are i.i.d. r.v. with $P(X_i=(-1)^kk)=C/k^2lnk$. Show that although $E|X_1|=\infty$, there exists a constant $\mu$ such that $S_n/n \rightarrow \mu$.

If I can show that $xP(|X_1|>x) \rightarrow 0$, then by weak law of large numbers, and dominate convergence theorem, I will prove that $S_n/n \rightarrow \mu$ in probability, where $\mu$ is the mean of $X_1$, which is finite by alternate series test.

$$xP(|X_1|>x)=x\sum_{k>x} C/k^2 \ln k$$

I tried to use the integration $\int_x^\infty \dfrac{1}{y^2\ln y} \mathrm dy$ and $\int_{x-1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{y^2\ln{y}}dy$ to bound the series.But no idea how to integrate $\dfrac{1}{y^2\ln{y}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to find an exact formula for the integral. You can simply apply the [*L'Hôpital's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) to conclude:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2 \log y}
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2 \log y}}{\frac{1}{x}}
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{x^2 \log x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}
= 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to integrate $\frac{1}{y^2 \log(y)}$ itself. It is enough to integrate something larger that is easy to integrate. Try the derivative of $-\frac{1}{x\log(x)}$ i.e. $$\frac{1}{x \log(x)} = \int_x^{\infty} \frac{\log(y) + 1}{y^2 \log(y)^2} \, \mathrm{d}y.$$